# Warning when trying to match two URL parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm incorporating React-Routing into a react app for the first time.

My intention is to embed two variables into the URL, such as

/project/ABC/person/123

where ABC is the project id and person 123 is the person id.

I've set up the following routes.

```
<Router>
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={PageIndex}/>
        <Route path="about" component={PageAbout}/>
        <Route path="people/:projectId" component={PagePeople}>
            <Route path="person/:personId" component={Person}/>
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
```

The app actually runs, and functions correctly, but the browser is throwing a console error.

Warning: Location "people/SE/person/2" did not match any routes

Any advice?

Thanks,

L.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this?
I think it will work fine.

```
<Router>
<Route path="/" component={App}>
    <IndexRoute component={PageIndex}/>
    <Route path="about" component={PageAbout}/>
    <Route path="people/:projectId" component={PagePeople}/>
    <Route path="people/:projectId/person/:personId" component={Person}/>
</Route>
```

Comment: Thanks, the route worked, and I restructured the page to fit.